# Variable value not updating in angular

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

```js
const req = new HttpRequest('POST', sampleurl, formData, { reportProgress: true, });
this.uploading = true;
this.httpClient
  .request<CertificateSubmissionResult[]>(req)
  .pipe(
    finalize(() => {
      this.uploading = false;
      this.selectedMainImageFiles = null;
    })
  )
  .subscribe(
    (event) => {
      if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
        this.uploadProgress = Math.round(
          (100 * event.loaded) / event.total
        );
      } else 
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        this.MainImageSubmissionResults = event.body as CertificateSubmissionResult[];
        if(this.MainImageSubmissionResults!=null){
          this.mainImageUrl = this.MainImageSubmissionResults[0].imagePath;
        }
      }
    }
);
```

After the second submit of this.mainImageUrl, the image is not updating. It is only showing the first uploaded image. Every time I upload this.mainImageUrl it is getting the updated value but it is not reflecting in the html. How do I solve this issue, can I use the |async pipe.. ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include your html, and show how you've verified that `this.mainImageUrl` is changing values.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way is to use ChangeDetectorRef. See the official sample at:  https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#use-markforcheck-with-checkonce-strategy
You need to inject it in component and call

```
this.ref.markForCheck();
```

when changing image url